# Increase performance inorder to refresh the whole page without using Ajax

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to increase the performance inorder to refresh the whole page using  javascript without using Ajax ? Can we maintain some caching or other technique to speed up the page refresh process ?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Browsers do cache pages by default. Let us know what specific problem you are facing. Generic questions are unanswerable and no one pays heed to them here.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you mean by refreshing the page, but something like this can be achieved through JavaScript only without AJAX.

Assume you have two section in your page. Contents of second section are dependent on value selected in section one but the variation is definitive. In that case you may want to load all the variation of second section and keep them hidden in the page. Once done, then based on the events in first section, you can just show/hide corresponding details in second section.

One common example of this scenario could be: List of countries and List of States example. Say you want to display the list of states if country is selected as US/Canada etc. and for rest of the countries, you want to display a free text field. In this scenario, you may pre-load the list of US states and list of Canada states and keep them hidden. Once user select any country, your can display the related states list/field in the UI. **All in client side.**